# How can i solve his "Cannot POST "/error nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a simple sign up page and when i press submit i get the "Cannot POST /controllers/register-controller"

## index in app/index.js

```
var express=require('express');
var parser=require("body-parser");
var connection=require("./config");
var registerController=require("./controllers/register-controller");
var app=express();
app.use(parser.json());
app.use(parser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/"+"index.html");
})

app.post('/api/register',registerController.register);
app.post('./controllers/register- 
controller',registerController.register);

app.listen(5000);
```

## register-controller in app/controller/register-controller.js

```
var express=require("express");
var connection=require("./../config");
module.exports.register=function(req,res){ 
  var date=new Date();
  var users={
    "first_name": req.body.first_name,
    "last_name": req.body.last_name,
    "email": req.body.email,
    "password": req.body.password,
    "created_at": date,
    "updated_at": date
};
connection.query('insert into users set ?'
,users,function(errors,results,fields){
  if(error){
     res.json({
      status: false,
      message: "Query Error"
    })
  }
  else{
    res.json({
      status: true,
      data: results,
      message: "Registeration success"
    })
  }
 });
}
```

## index.html in app/index.html

```
form action="./controllers/register-controller" method="POST">
  First Name: input type="text" name="first_name"<br/>
  Last Name:  input type="text" name="last_name"<br/>
  Email:      input type="text" name="email"><br/>
  Password:   input type="password" name="password"></br>

  input type="submit" value="Submit"
/form
```

I am new to this and i dont know what to change. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your request, server port and path from your browser's network tab by pressing Ctrl+shift+i

Comment: change this ./controllers/register-controller to /api/register

Comment: Change your form action "./controllers/register-controller" to "/api/register", i think it solves your problem because you have defined  "/api/register" routes for register action

Comment: @shiva  Thanks a lot. I understood and it worked